# Python IDE recommendation on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am new to Python and Ubuntu. Using it to learning Machine learning. so it learning 3 things at same time.

As of now I am trying out of code on terminal, any recommendation which IDE to use ?

Comment: Try PyCharm. If you need to maintain notebooks, try Jupyter or Zeppline.

Comment: VS Code is a good solution

Comment: I like to use Jupyter Notebook, as machine learning requires lot of visualization during development. It's not the best but many people like using that.

Comment: I suggest *not* using a full-fledged IDE like PyCharm if you are a beginner. Especially in languages like Python, there really isn't any need, and using IDE's is not great from a pedagogical point of view, a know a ton of kids who would be completely lost without Eclipse to do even basic Java projects, and I think there is even less of an excuse to use one in Python. I'd stick with a text editor. Try VS Code, and once you learn more and more, you can start adding extensions and it will practically be a full-fledged IDE. Nothing will serve you better than learning to use your terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Jupyter notebook. You could use this by installing Anaconda. For developing your applications further, you may still want to try Pycharm later.

But I would really recommend you to first go with Jupyter notebook because it allows to run a part of your code and check the results below it. It will help you to understand your code well.